# Hash Table + Binary Search

Tags: hashtable, binary-search

I'm using an Hash Table to store some values. Here are the details:

1. There will be roughly 1M items to store (not known before, so no perfect-hash possible).
2. Table is 10M large.
3. Hash function is MurMurHash3.

I did some tests and storing 1M values I get 350,000 collisions and 30 elements at the most-colliding hash table's slot.

Are these result good?

Would it make sense to implement Binary Search for lists that get created at colliding hash-table's slots?

What' your advice to improve performances?

EDIT: Here is my code

```
var
  HashList: array [0..10000000 - 1] of Integer;

for I := 0 to High(HashList) do
  HashList[I] := 0;

for I := 1 to 1000000 do
begin
  Y := MurmurHash3(UIntToStr(I));
  Y := Y mod Length(HashList);
  Inc(HashList[Y]);
  if HashList[Y] > 1 then
    Inc(TotalCollisionsCount);
  if HashList[Y] > MostCollidingSlotItemCount then
    MostCollidingSlotItemCount := HashList[Y];
end;

Writeln('Total: ' + IntToStr(TotalCollisionsCount) + ' Max: ' + IntToStr(MostCollidingSlotItemCount));
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Total: 48169 Max: 5
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) You distribute 1M items over 10M boxes? 2) What is your definition of collision?

Comment: 1) Yes
2) Two different keys that map to the same slot in the table

Comment: expected number of elements per cell when filled randomly: 0: 9048K 1: 905K 2: 45K 3:1K5 4:50 Conclusion: your hashfunction is terrible (or your data contains duplicates)

Comment: I tried to hash decimals numers (as string) from 1 to 1000000. I got same results with SHA1, too.

Comment: Check your strings. For numeric keys, multiplying by a large odd number (preferrably prime) is just as good as a *real* hash function.

Comment: But is it normal to get these result even with SHA1?

Comment: [You didn't show any code, and I don't have a crystal ball] Maybe you made another error. Do note that numeric strings come from a very small alphabet `[0-9]`, and some hash functions are sensitive to this. (but murmur ansd SHA1 are probably okay in this respect). Instead of a hash function, test with a (good) random number.

Comment: After the update: `Am I missing something?` Yes, 48169 is not 350,000. And your results are comparable to my simulation, thus more or less optimal.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The results I posted initially where with a list of 16M with 4M elements. But at the end, what should be the perfect table size factor vs number of items to store?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when you put 1M items *randomly* into 10M cells

```
calendar_size=10000000 nperson = 1000000
E/cell| Ncell | frac   |  Nelem   |  frac  |h/cell|  hops  | Cumhops
----+---------+--------+----------+--------+------+--------+--------
  0:  9048262 (0.904826)        0 (0.000000)     0        0        0
  1:   905064 (0.090506)   905064 (0.905064)     1   905064   905064
  2:    45136 (0.004514)    90272 (0.090272)     3   135408  1040472
  3:     1488 (0.000149)     4464 (0.004464)     6     8928  1049400
  4:       50 (0.000005)      200 (0.000200)    10      500  1049900
----+---------+--------+----------+--------+------+--------+--------
  5: 10000000             1000000                1.049900    1049900
```

The left column is the number of items in a cell. The second: the number of cells having this itemcount.

---

WRT the binary search: it is obvious that for small tables like this (maximum chain length=4, but most chains are of length=1), linear search outperforms binary search. The takeover-point is probably somewhere between 10 and 100.